# Valgrind complains about "Create system partion fail"

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

I use Valgrind and I get "Create system partion fail"。

Details following:

```
# valgrind --log-file=pau.val --leak-check=full --error-limit=no --track-origins=yes --show-leak-kinds=all --time-stamp=yes ./rm.pau 63,11,0,0,2 231
 Enter DEV Main Proc !
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(15
) , pcOptValue(15).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(15
) , pcOptValue(15).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(15
) , pcOptValue(15).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(15
) , pcOptValue(15).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(15
) , pcOptValue(15).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(15
) , pcOptValue(15).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(15
) , pcOptValue(15).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(15
) , pcOptValue(15).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(51
) , pcOptValue(51).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(51
) , pcOptValue(51).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(51
) , pcOptValue(51).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(51
) , pcOptValue(51).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(51
) , pcOptValue(51).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(51
) , pcOptValue(51).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(51
) , pcOptValue(51).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(2) and ulstrlen2(2) acBuffer(51
) , pcOptValue(51).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(8) and ulstrlen2(8) acBuffer(80000001
) , pcOptValue(80000001).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(8) and ulstrlen2(8) acBuffer(50000000
) , pcOptValue(50000000).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(8) and ulstrlen2(8) acBuffer(20000000
) , pcOptValue(20000000).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]ulstrlen1(6) and ulstrlen2(6) acBuffer(520000
) , pcOptValue(520000).
 [CGL_SetOSPerformanceOpt]pcfileName and pcOptValue is same.set_capability:    enter
set_capability:    uid = 560, gid = 1600
set_capability:    getresuid(&uid, &euid, &suid) ret = 0
set_capability:    getresgid(&gid, &egid, &sgid) ret = 0
set_capability:    uid = 0, euid = 0, suid = 0, gid = 0, egid = 0, sgid = 0
set_capability:    getresuid(&uid, &euid, &suid) ret = 0
set_capability:    getresgid(&gid, &egid, &sgid) ret = 0
set_capability:    uid = 0, euid = 560, suid = 0, gid = 0, egid = 0, sgid = 0
set_capability:    set_capability:  OK!

++++user input para is:         ulSubRack=63, ulSlot=11, ulSubSlot=0, ulCupId=0, ulProcNo=2, ulNetCell=231++++

Finally SYS_PARA config info is:

g_stProcSysPara.ulMemDopraPTSize = 2000000000

g_stProcSysPara.ulMemUserPTSize = 1048576

g_stProcSysPara.ulMemExtraPTSize = 0

g_stProcSysPara.ulMemReservedSize = 4194304

g_stProcSysPara.ulBoxHighMemSize = 1048576

g_stProcSysPara.ulBoxLowMemSize = 1048576

g_stProcSysPara.ulMaxSysMsgUnit = 100000

g_stProcSysPara.ulMaxMsgUnit = 100000

g_stProcSysPara.ulMaxSysMsgs = 5000

g_stProcSysPara.ulMaxRelTimers = 50000

g_stProcSysPara.ulDbLogBufferLen = 1048576
Supported 32 ELF file class: 1!
 ENTER VOS_Start.........

[LOG-ERR] File=vos_mempt.c, Line=6939, Module=8472, Errno=10016. 
[DOPRA-vosMemPtAlloc]:malloc(2000000000) fail.

[LOG-ERR] File=vos_mempt.c, Line=1199, Module=8472, Errno=10016. 
[DOPRA-vosMemPtCreateEx]:pszPtName(SYSPT), alloc memory(2000000000) fail.

[LOG-ERR] File=vos_mempt.c, Line=992, Module=8472, Errno=10016. 
[Dopra-vosMemPtCreatePt]:Create Pt SYSPT Failed


[LOG-ERR] File=vos_mempt.c, Line=778, Module=8472, Errno=10016. 
[DOPRA-vosMemPtInit]:Create system partion fail. partion size:2000000000
[DOPRA-seqcbInvoke]: vosMemPtInit failed for vos_mempt(ret=555231008).
[DOPRA-VOS_Start]: Unable to load module(s):VOS_DEFAULT_STARTUP_SET.

 [VOS_Start] Start up failed!
```

I got confused if the memory I set is too large.

here is the `top` detail:

```
# top
top - 06:28:44 up 10 days,  1:11,  3 users,  load average: 3.25, 3.62, 3.60
Tasks: 165 total,   1 running, 164 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  2.8%us,  2.1%sy,  0.4%ni, 94.4%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:     24161M total,     8215M used,    15945M free,      479M buffers
Swap:        0M total,        0M used,        0M free,     2568M cached
```

Comment: First of all, what output is from Valgrind, and what is the output of your program? I don't recognize any of the output you show as coming from Valgrind. Then regarding the allocation: When you allocate memory, all that memory has to be *contiguous*, i.e. it has to be one single chunk. If that's not possible, then the `malloc` call will fail.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand what the output means. Does the `output` means the file `pau.val`? I have paste all the detail that valgrind print into console(but most of the detail is my program's log).

Comment: _partion_ or _partition_?